# Convert http to https in .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, https, .net-core

I have asp.net core application. It works well but we are going to use https then. What I have to do?
Steps in local development and in production?

For example, in local the url is `http://localhost:12345`; but we want `https://localhost:12345`

**update:**

In production I am talking about hosting in IIS

Comment: Do you have a https cert for localhost? https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: I guess no. But does every developer need to have his own https cert on his machine? Or a common one?

Comment: Do you mean you need  [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: localhost https comes out of the box. if you mean while hosting, append the question with more information on where you are hosting

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, I am not sure your comment. In local dev, we don't use IIS Express, it is .net core + angular project. In production we host it on IIS I guess.

Comment: for local host if you created this with visual studio and it was version 2.1+ it will have a https with a different port number. you can check the launch json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In local development, you don't have to change anything if you're using IIS to expose your service.

In IIS either

- check 'require SSL' for your site under 'SSL settings'
- or if you want to redirect http traffic to https; do NOT check 'require SSL', but add a redirect rule

Like so

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Do we have to install some cert etc, could you please share some images(snapshot)?

Comment: I can't beat the Microsoft docs for that: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO14335.html

Comment: On your development machine you can simply use http. No need to test against a https service.